# Private Rancher failed to install monitoring tools

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, rancher

I am working with a **private** K8s cluster which managed by Rancher.

I'd like to integrate Rancher with monitoring tools (Prometheus, Grafana,...). An easy way to do it is using Cluster Tools on Rancher UI; but this way is impossible without Internet Connection.

Then, I found a helm chart for it, the `kube-prometheus-stack`. I've pushed all the neccessary images to my private registry, also the helm chart to chartmuseum. I installed this chart by using "Apps" tab on Rancher UI.

However, the installation process took about 1-2 mins and had no return notifications. I checked it out and one namespace was newly created, but no workloads inside. Thus, I went to check the log files of Rancher, but nothing special found.

So I want to check the logs of Rancher during this installation; or does anyone know any potential problems causing my failed installation or any other ways to install monitoring tools for private K8s clusters?

Thank you.

P/s:
My Rancher version: 2.7.1
Kubernetes version: 1.24.9I have configured to the right endpoints of images registry and charts repository.

Comment: I succeeded in installing this helm chart on my private K8s cluster.

At first, I tried `helm install` instead of installation through Rancher UI. Then I saw the logs of Events on Rancher UI.
Then, the real problems appeared. There are some dependencies whose docker images are configured with public registry by default. I couldn't find these configs in `Chart.yml` or `values.yml`. 
I had to change them all to my private registry (of course with related images available there). Then all required Pods (Deployments) are active.

Answer (score 0):

You can install monitoring tools like grafana and prometheus without the internet by using two methods: manifests and Helm Charts. Using manifests the installation process is bit intensive for complex setups but in helm charts we can install complex deployments easily. Customization  is limited in manifest but helm charts offer advanced customization. Hence installing a helm chart is the preferred method. You can find steps for Installing Prometheus on Kubernetes using Helm in this [document](https://www.squadcast.com/blog/install-prometheus-kubernetes#strongbest-practices-for-installing-prometheus-on-kubernetesstrong:%7E:text=cluster%20using%20Helm.-,Installing%20Prometheus%20on%20Kubernetes%20using%20Helm%C2%A0,-Before%20installing%20Prometheus).
Try using the below methods to install monitoring tools using private registry:

1. Try [enabling monitoring for use with SSL](https://ranchermanager.docs.rancher.com/how-to-guides/advanced-user-guides/monitoring-alerting-guides/enable-monitoring#enable-monitoring-for-use-without-ssl) by creating secrets.
2. As per this [git link](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/issues/336#issuecomment-745569146) you can create a grafana dashboard using configmaps, you can find the yaml in this [git link](https://github.com/23ewrdtf/notes/blob/master/Grafana/Readme.MD).
3. Try deploying using the manifest file after pushing the image and dependency into the registry:

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: prometheus
spec:
  selector:
    app: prometheus
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 9090
```

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prometheus
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: prometheus
          image: <local-registry>/prom/prometheus:v2.30.3
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 9090
```

Use the above yaml file to deploy prometheus in Rancher.Similarly for grafana you can follow this [document](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/installation/kubernetes/#troubleshooting).

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. Actually I managed to run all necessary deployments from kube-prometheus-stack, by `helm install` command. Anyway, despite of all those running deployments, when I tried to click on monitoring dashboard, I always get "Resource Unavailable", still figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out all the problems. So here is the summary of my `kube-prometheus-stack` deployment on a private K8s cluster.

First of all, installation with Rancher will be easy only if all your configurations are correct. So pay attention to any configuration requiring Internet connection (a public image registry, for e.g). In my case, I got a private Harbor registry, so I have changed all the registry config in `kube-prometheus-stack` chart from public ones to my Harbor.

At this time, I could run `helm install` and make all deployments active. But the `Monitoring` tab on Rancher kept telling me `Resource Unavailable`. Then I had to use the Inspect (F12) on my browser to see what made Rancher monitoring failed. And I discovered something...

Rancher was sending request to an endpoint which didn't exist to get Monitoring resources. That endpoint was defaultly configured in Rancher, and can only be usable **if you install `rancher-monitoring` app via Cluser Tools on a public Rancher**. That endpoint indicates the default namespace and services' names of `rancher-monitoring` components.

Then, the last thing I need to do is changing the name of my chart from `kube-prometheus-stack` to `rancher-monitoring`, then install it in a suitable namespace (from the default endpoint).

And finally, it worked.